# webrtc android with io.pristine:libjingle

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

I am trying to use **io.pristine:libjingle** for one of WebRTC project. I found one Sample on Github.

1- I have my WebRTC server ready which making Audio and Video Calls from Chrome Browser through user authentication 
2- I need connect my WebRtc server through UserID and Password
3- I needs to make and receive Audio and Video Call

Any Sample for such functions for **io.pristine:libjingle**

Answer (score 1):

Use this demo code - https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc
And you can test this app using apprtc.appspot.com

Use this blog too - https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Introduction-to-WebRTC-on-Android/